# winforms opacity problem

Tags: c#, winforms, opacity

Hi I want to set opacity for a form in page load.

I try to set the opacity like this

this.Opacity = 10;  in paage load but it is not working.

May i know the reason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opacity is a double value out of `1.0`. If you want 10%, use `0.1`.

Comment: ya it is working.. but here i want to hide the same form. So i have given like this this.Hide() but it is  not working still form is visible